# How to force changed master history to feature branches based on old history?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-cherry-pick, git-rewrite-history

My colleague changed history of our `master` and my `feature-branch` is based on old history of `master`s. Simple rebase didn't change my branchs' history to the new (changed) history.

Is cherry picking my only option or is there a simpler way to solve this? Creating a new branch would mess up our comment history on Gitlab about merge request. Also not sure what would happen with Gitlabs auto merge with differing histories.

Desired outcome would be similar history on `master` and `feature-branch` with `feature-branch` having my commits on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Update your local version of master (it will be a forced update (marked with a + sign in fetch output) since histories differ)

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Then you'll be able to cherry-pick or rebase your commits on top of newly updated master. Here with cherry-pick :

```
git checkout feature-branch
git log
# in git log output, spot the commit SHAs of the commits you need ans store them

git cherry-pick <commitSHA> <otherCommitSHA>
```

(Conflicts might arise. If so, resolve them as usual)

Now your `feature-branch` can be merged back into `master` (arguably through a PR) without history problems.